# 3D Trigonometry: finding a point in space along the surface of a sphere

Tags: math, 3d, coordinates, trigonometry

I have a two points in 3D space, let's say (0, 0, 0) and (5, 5, 0)

and I have a camera at (0,0,5)

Given this, the first point (0,0,0) is closer to the camera than the second. What I would like to do is have that second point be limited in distance from the camera point, so that it (or really any hypothetical point) cannot be farther away from the camera point than the distance of my control point (0,0,0).

What is the mathematical apparatus I can use to calculate a point in space that is the same vector from the camera, but not as far away?

I hope this makes sense... and I wish I had taken any math classes higher than basic algebra.

Comment: This doesn't really involve any trigonometry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand this correctly. You have point lets P1 (x1, y1 , z1) and a distance **D** and another point P2 (x2 , y2 , z2) and you want another point P3 so that it is in the same direction as P2 but only distance **D** from P1. if that is the case.

Direction **V1** from P1 to P2 is  **( P2 - P1 ) ie ( x2 - x1 , y2 - y1 , z2 - z1 )**

Unit vector from **V1** would **U1**

```
U1 = V1 / distance between ( P1 , P2)
```

[Formula for distance between two points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance#Three_dimensions)

And finally P3 will be a distance of **D** along this unit vector

```
P3 = P1 +  U1 * D
```

Comment: I'm working right now on trying to implement this. I'll let you know how it turns out. Thanks

Comment: Actually Para I need to correct you. What I need is NOT a P3 in the same DIRECTION as P2, but I need a P3 that is the same DISTANCE as P2 but a different direction.

Comment: Even for that case the answer pretty much covers it... you need to replace `D = distance(P1,P2)`

Answer (score 1):

First, take the vector from camera (0,0,5), let's call it `C`, to the point (5, 5, 0), let's call it `P`:

```
V = P - C
```

Then adapt the length of this vector to the target length (in this case 5), let's call it `L`:

```
V' = V * (L / |V|)
```

And then just add this again to `C`, to get the final point `P'`:

```
P' = C + V'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use an additional parameter to modify the length of the vector. If the original point is `(5, 5, 0)`, then you could use `(5t, 5t, 0t)` and find a value of `t` which will result in the vector being the correct length. The modified vector will be in the same direction as the original only shorter.

To calculate the length of a vector use `length = sqrt(x^2, y^2, z^2)`.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want? Capital letter variables are 3D vectors, and small letters are scalars.

1. Starting Point `P1 = { 0, 0, 0 }`
2. Camera Point `C = { 0, 0, 5 }`
3. Distance `r = DIST(C, P1)`
4. Second Point `P2 = { 5, 5, 0 }`
5. Direction Vector `E=UNIT(P2-C)`
6. Second Point `P2 = C + r*E`

Use these operators

```
DOT(P,Q) = P[0]*Q[0]+P[1]*Q[1]+P[2]*Q[2];
UNIT(P) = P/sqrt(DOT(P,P);
DIST(P,Q) = sqrt(DOT(P-Q,P-Q));
t*P =  { t*P[0], t*P[1], t*P[2] };
P/d =  { P[0]/d, P[1]/d, P[2]/d };
```